# Changing three.js background to opacity .5

Tags: javascript, three.js, transparency

Ok So I am trying to make the background of the canvas/three.js to something that will be like `opacity:.5` I can make it completely transparent with
 `new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );`

but this isn't what I am looking for I want to be able to see behind the render(canvas background) so I can see the body/html of the page below but keep the objects in the render `opacity:1`.

Any idea's?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set the clear color and alpha value of the renderer like the following in order to have more control about how the background is rendered:

```
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } );
renderer.setClearColor( color );
renderer.setClearAlpha( 0.5 );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vr648d3z/1/

Comment: MrDoob told me not to use `setClearColor`. That I should always use `scene.background = new THREE.Color(...)`  Has that advice changed?

Comment: I was not aware of that. I personally think `scene.background` is okay as long as you don't need a transparent background color. Using `setClearColor()` in combination with `setClearAlpha()` seems more comprehensible to me.

Comment: One line: `renderer.setClearColor( 0xff0000, 0.5 );`

Comment: That's even nicer ;)

Comment: As @WestLangley said I ended up doing `setClearColor( 0x000000, .5 );` along with setting `alpha: true`